# iOS video/audio calls with webRTC using UIWebView or any alternative

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, webrtc

Im working with integrating my iOS app with [ladesk Live agent](https://www.ladesk.com/), they don't have an SDK for iOS neither android, you have to embed a unique URL in a `UIWebView` as per the [integration instructions](https://support.ladesk.com/498003-Chat-for-mobile-apps)

but it is faced a fact that the video / call button needs to work with webRTC. The WebRTC framework that is responsible for voice functionality in the browser, however webRTC is not available in the mobile versions of web browsers.

The best thing I found is [A WebRTC browser for iOS developed in the open. Bowser is built on top of OpenWebRTC.](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/bowser) but it didn't work, and had same results as doing the same with `UIWebView`

Any ideas in Objective c or swift?

Comment: You can try Kurento Webrtc framework with Android, iOS, and browser.I had tried Kurento for iOS, Android and chrome browser. I think it will help you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that, since I found no helpful thing about it

Comment: check this link for [KMS installation](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html) and for iOS client [check this](https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS)

Comment: how can I use it with UIWebView

Comment: I have not tried with UIWebView @Mutawe

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to use WebRTC in a UIWebView (or its successor WKWebView) since WebRTC is only available in the Safari app on iOS.

The only way forward is to use a WebRTC stack (like [Apprtc](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios)) and implement your own solution based on that.